# How to clear all cache data of google-chrome (installed on lubuntu 22.04) by commands executed by a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, google-chrome, cache

Initially I have written this question for a system with lubuntu 18.04 installed and for that distribution the question is off-topic.

**But I have to solve exactly the same problem for the distribution lubuntu 22.04 which is yet under support**.

#### The question

I have installed google-chrome version 114. I need to clear the cache of google-chrome at every boot.
To do that I have created a bash script which contains the following commands:

- `rm -rf /home/myuser/.cache/google-chrome/*`
- `rm -rf /home/myuser/.config/google-chrome/Default/*`

The script is executed at any boot before to start google-chrome.

Here I'm asking if the previous commands are enough to delete all cache data or I must execute other operations.

Thanks